# Differential equation $\cos(f')=\cos(f)'$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation

$$\sin(f')=\sin(f)'$$

has the trivial solution $f=0$. Does the equation

$$\cos(f')=\cos(f)'$$

have any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are two separable equations.

From
$$\sin(f')=\cos(f)f'$$
we deduce
$$\text{sinc}(f')=\cos(f)$$and the non-trivial solution
$$\int\frac{df}{\text{sinc}^{-1}(\cos(f))}=x+C.$$

And from $$\cos(f')=-\sin(f)f',$$
defining $g(t)=\cos(t)/t$ (there is no standard *cardinal cosine*), we have
$$g(f')=-\sin(f),$$and
$$\int \frac{df}{g^{-1}(-\sin(f))}=x+C.$$

As the functions are not univocally invertible, several branches are possible.

Comment: Why this downvote ?